# jQuery - AJAX beforeSend

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

This AJAX call is not doing action beforeSend, though the ajax request is working as it should be. This function gets called from a button received from a different ajax call. What do I need to change here?

```
<%= image_tag 'wait.gif', :id => 'wait_icon', :style => "display:none;"%>

$(function(){
  $('#add_remove_button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "/item/add_remove", 
      success: function(data) { $('#view_item').html(data); },
      beforeSend: function() { getElementById('wait_icon').style.display='block'; 
      /*$('#wait_icon').show();*/#Tried this too 
      },
      data: $('#test').serialize(),
      error: function(){  },
      success: function(data){   },
      complete: function (){   }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: tried making the style , display:block at first?

Comment: Are you getting errors  in the console?

Comment: @gdoron - There are no errors on console.

Comment: @rjmcb - tried display:block, didn't make any difference.

Comment: does it mean, you're not creating the div element?

Answer (score 3):

Try changing this

```
getElementById('wait_icon').style.display='block';
```

to this

```
document.getElementById('wait_icon').style.display='block';
```

Comment: Made that change, but still something else is wrong. Isn't working. :/